# Type provider: How to regenerate?

Tags: f#, type-providers

How would you make the `LINQ-TO-SQL` type provider, generate or/and regenerate the classes?

I've just added a new table to my database, and the type provider can't figure that out. I've tried to delete the line with the type provider, and type it once more - no luck. I've also tried to do a rebuild.. still no luck.

**Edit:**

I've defined the type provider like:

```
[<Generate>]
type dbSchema = SqlDataConnection<"conString">
```

and using it like:

`let ctx = dbSchema.GetDataContext()`

Comment: Please provide some code

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You're right - this seems to be quite tricky. I'm using `SqlDataConnection` type provider in a script file and the only way to update the schema that I've found so far is to make some minor (irrelevant) change in the connection string. For example, add space after `=` of one of the parameters:

```
[<Generate>]
type Northwind = TypeProviders.SqlDataConnection
  <"data source=.\\sqlexpress;initial catalog=Northwind;integrated security=True">

[<Generate>]
type Northwind = TypeProviders.SqlDataConnection
  <"data source=.\\sqlexpress;initial catalog=Northwind;integrated security= True">

//                                                                          ^ here
```

The schema seems to be cached using connection string as the key, so if you change it back, you get the old schema again. I guess this is probably a bug, so adding whitespace is a possible workaround.

There is also a parameter `ForceUpdate`, but that doesn't seem to have any effect and [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh362320%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) doesn't say much about it.

Comment: The "irrelevant change to the string" is indeed one working way to force an update; we're aware of the API/usability issues here and we will have something better for the eventual Beta.

Comment: any news on this? it's been >4 years and I'm making irrelevant changes to the connection string when I need an update, and wishing I didn't have to.

Comment: Little question: what happens when the type provider is trying to access a resource which is not available at compile-time (internet down, or remote host down, etc...)?

Comment: Six years later, is the recommended practice still to insert benign garbage into the connection string?

Comment: It is now the year of our lord, two-thousand twenty, we continually inserteth spaces hither and yon to regenerate types, as prescribed by this tome.