# Sql type provider ignores changes in .dbml file

Tags: f#, type-providers, sqlmetal

I use the dbml like this:

```
type S = DbmlFile<"db.dbml", ResolutionFolder = @".">
```

After I removed a column in one of the database tables and regenerated the dbml the requests to this table continued to contain the column. So, I was getting invalid column error until I copy/pasted the dbml file to file with different name and set to run my code with the new file one time. Only after that I was able to return to the old file.

This is definitely a bug. But I need at least simpler workaround for this. Is there any cache folder which I could clean on schema change or something like that?

Looks like the same problem but without .dbml files: [Type provider: How to regenerate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7821260/type-provider-how-to-regenerate?rq=1)
Will try it next time.

UPDATE: The issue is not stable. After it happened first time I had done 3 schema updates without the error. And today it happened again. The workaround from the referenced answer helps indeed. I mean addition of space like:

```
type S = DbmlFile<"db.dbml ", ResolutionFolder = @".">
```

Comment: Instruction: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/tutorials/type-providers/troubleshooting-type-providers  does not help (problem type: Schema Changes)?

Comment: If you mean clean or rebuild then no, it does not help.